# Finance Projects in Python

Tags: quant-trading-strategies, trading, algorithmic-trading, python, quantitative

I am new to this forum. I work in the Market Risk Domain at a leading Investment Bank. I am currently learning Python. And the best way to learn is to experiment with some Real Live Analysis/Project(My way of learning).

I will be really grateful if someone can give me some ideas on what kind of Quantitative Finance project I can try out on Python.

I was thinking more in the lines of some automated trading algo to start of with. Something that I can do with publicly available data. Suggestions are very much welcome. Don't want to start with something very complicated.

Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: Hi Deb, welcome to Quant.SE! You could literally try to build anything, you'll have to figure out what you like building most.

Comment: still very broad, but maybe the set-up of the question is confusing too. You work in Market Risk but if I understand correctly you want to work on an automated trading algo. These words can mean many things too many people but these seem distinct areas or not?

Comment: Yes I do work in Market Risk. But I am very much interested in Automated Trading and Derivatives Pricing, so would like to pursue some project on these lines for my own benefits. I am not sure if I can build something on Market risk with public data. I thought of automated trading because after implementing it I can actually work with live data and see if it really works or not.

Comment: Too broad, however I've a few suggestions: you reimplement or hack on some of the code mentioned on this site under the Python tag. Another idea is to practice on https://www.stockfighter.io (Disclaimer: I was a beta tester). You'll have to consider whether your employer allows this kind of activity though.

Comment: @BobJansen, why would anyone want to contribute IP free of charge when there are numerous challenges with high price awards (Kaggle and Netflix comes to mind) and/or public exposure to get potentially hired by high profile companies? Looks more like the engineering/developer equivalent of the Millenniums/World Quants that constantly look to "harvest" IP on the cheap or free-of-charge.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37948/discussion-on-question-by-deb-finance-projects-in-python).